# Spring boot does not recognise implementation of interface as an @autowire candidate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

A class implementing an interface is not recognised by Spring Auto-Wire when required in a different package

I'm facing a problem with spring boot auto-wiring.

I have 2 spring boot projects: (A) and (B). Project (A) implements some common REST API route handlers and is added to Project (B) as a jar dependency.

Project A has the following:

```
package com.example.projectA;

public interface MyCustomInterface {
    public void doStuff();
}
```

```
package com.example.projectA;

@RestController
public class TestEndpoint {
    private final MyCustomInterface provider;

    @Autowired
    public TestEndpoint(MyCustomInterface provider) {
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    @GetMapping("api/test")
    public ResponseEntity<String> test() {
        System.out.println("Provider: " + provider);
        provider.doStuff();
        return new ResponseEntity<>("OK", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Project B has the following:

```
package com.example.projectB;

@RestController
public class MyCustomInterfaceProvider implements MyCustomInterface {

    @Override
    public void doStuff() {
    }

}
```

However, when I start up project B application like this

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.example.projectA")
public class MyProjectBApplication {
//...
}
```

Spring complains that there are no beans that match MyCustomInterface which is required for a constructor of TestEndpoint.

`Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.projectA.TestEndpoint required a bean of type 'com.example.projectA.MyCustomInterface' that could not be found.`

What I have tried so far and confirmed:

1. jar file of project (A) is added to project (B) correctly as it gets picked up by ComponentScan successfully
2. MyCustomInterface that MyCustomInterfaceProvider implements and MyCustomInterface from TestEndpoint constructor are one and the same interface
3. Carrying over code of TestEndpoint into Project (B) works as expected - auto wiring succeeds.

Appreciate any help and advise!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the implementation of the interface in projectB, but you are scanning in projectA package. Where is the implementation in projectA?

Try adding `projectB` to this:

`@ComponentScan("com.example.projectA")`

Comment: Thank you! That worked! I assumed since Project B was the application that was getting started components from within it would be included automatically, but they were not! This fixed it!

Comment: They *are* included automatically, unless you use the `@ComponentScan` annotation in which case you have to explicitly specify all packages